# Equal strings (string and string of array)-c++

Tags: c++

I dont understand how to compare between string in c++??

```
string s1="abc";
string s[]={"abc","vsj"};
int length=sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);//length of s
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
 if(s[i].compare(s1))
{
 cout<<"One of the string equal to s1";
}
}
```

Is it possible??
Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Do you want just equality or ordering? Equality is easy: `if(s1 == s[i])`

Comment: `std::string` overloads the `==` operator so you can do thinkgs like `str1 == str2`

Comment: The `compare` member function returns `0` if the arguments are equal. Your check therefore has to be `if(!s[i].compare(s1))`. But for the equality case the equality operator is overloaded for `std::string`, so you can also just write `if(s[i] == s1)` which is easier to read and understand even for someone who doesn't know C++.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` overloads `operator==`. You can compare 2 string using `operato==`. Also you can use `std::vector` instead of array. Using c++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1="abc";
    vector<string> ss = { "abc", "vsj" };
    for (auto &s: ss) {
        if (s == s1) {
            cout<<"One of the string equal to s1";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using c++98:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1="abc";
    vector<string> ss;
    ss.push_back("abc");
    ss.push_back("vsj");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ss.size(); ++i) {
        if (ss.at(i) == s1) {
            cout<<"One of the string equal to s1";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

compare return the same values as [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):
<0 - the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2
0 - the contents of both strings are equal
>0 - the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2